# how to create a page object with css identifer & attribute

Tags: page-object-gem

How do i define page object with css identifier with attribute

```
For example,
<div class="presc" date-range="3 months">3m</div>
<div class="presc selected" date-range="6 months">6m</div>
<div class="presc" date-range="1 year">1y</div>
```

how do i use attribute name data-range?

```
div(:date_range_3m, css:div.prescription[@data-range = '3 month')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessor you want is:

```
div(:date_range_3m, css: 'div.presc[date-range~="3"][date-range~="months"]')
```

Some notes about the changes/problems:

- The `date-range="3 months"` is considered an attribute with a space separated value list. For these types of values, you can only compare against each of the individual words. This is why the suggested selector has `[date-range~="3"][date-range~="months"]`. Note that this has the problem that it will also match `date-range="months 3"` as well as `date-range="3 months some other values"`.
- The class value is "presc" rather than "prescription".
- The attribute on the element is actually "date-range" instead of "data-range".
- Unlike XPath, CSS-selectors do not prefix the attribute with "@"
- The quotations around the CSS value are missing.
- There is a mismatched ending bracket - it should be "]" instead of a ")".

Comment: Thank you Justin.  That was helpful. I have a question though.   How to write css selector for nested div.  Say for example          s  <div class="timeline-search">
  <div id="timeline-search-container">
    <div id="prescribed-range" class="prescribed-range">
      <div class="presc" date-range="3 month">3m</div>
      <div class="presc selected" date-range="6 month">6m</div>
      <div class="presc" date-range="1 year">1y</div>

Comment: You will want to read about [child and/or descendant selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/), which is basically a separation of elements by ">" or " " respectively. For example, depending on what nesting you expect, you could something like `#prescribed-range > div.presc[date-range~="3"][date-range~="months"]` or `div.timeline-search div.presc[date-range~="3"][date-range~="months"]`